# what's the right expression to say ' you can take our wine in cups'?¿

Tags: phrases

I want to indicate that in our restaurant we offer the wine in bootle (as always), but you can take cups of wine too. How to say This cups of wine? thanks.

Comment: Wine is sold both by the botte and  by the cup/glass.

Comment: The standard term is *"glass of wine"* (***not** "cup"*). So if you let customers buy one glass of wine, you would say *"we also sell wine by the glass"* (or *"you can also buy wine by the glass"* if you want phrasing closer to your question).

Comment: @Josh61: A ***cup** of wine* sounds positively medieval to me. Right up there with [*cup of mead*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cup+of+mead%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), which is/was almost three times more common than [*glass of mead*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22glass+of+mead%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree..but not that medieval after all. :)) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cup+of+wine%2C+glass+of+wine&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccup%20of%20wine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglass%20of%20wine%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61: Dunno 'bout that. The graph clearly shows a long-term decline in ***cup** of wine*. More tellingly, look at the shift in *relative* prevalence over the past few decades (essentially, during *my* "drinking career"! :)

Comment: You might get better answers at ell.SE

Answer (score 3):

Individual servings of wine are sold ***[by the glass](http://www.starchefs.com/cook/features/wines-by-the-glass)***, or as *glasses of wine*. Conventionally, we say wine is served in *[glasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_glass)*, rather than *cups*, even though technically a wine glass is a type of cup. See *[What's the difference between “cup” and “glass”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75729)* for that topic.